# activity indicator tableview in swift

Tags: swift, animation

when the view is opened I want the animation to start, then get the data (download) and then stop after the download is complete. Wouldn't it be great if the below code would work! Well, it's probably not that simple.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    getDataFromDatamanager()
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: If you have a question about something you should probably make it a little more specific as im insure what you want you are asking

Comment: what does `getDataFromDatamanager()` do? Grab information from server side? Or locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have everything running nicely. You start call the `startAnimating()` method. However, you aren't checking to make sure that your `getDataFromDatamanager()` is complete. So right now what is going on is your `activityIndicator` is animating and immediately stopping the animation because you aren't checking if the `getDataFromDatamanager()` has completed executing. What you need to do is create a [completion handler](http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/9/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift) for your `getDataFromDatamanager()` and in that completion handler you have to call `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`

*Also, if you need help creating a completion handler there are many tutorials on the web. I can't really help you in creating a completion handler without more code being present.*

**Edit:**
Just to add a bit more information to my answer. The reason it is starting and immediately stopping is because the `getDataFromDatamanager()` is *asynchronous* which means that your code won't wait for `getDataFromDatamanager()` to finish executing. `getDataFromDatamanager()` will run on a different thread and skip over that line and will call `stopAnimating()` immediately which is why you have to check for `getDataFromDatamanager()` to finish executing and one such way of doing that is by using a `completionHandler`.